# How to read files in flink if its raw log file using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to read raw log file in flink to process it to kinesis .However in flink scala how to  read raw files instead of using text file since text file create DataStream[String] which creates issue in formatting.I have tried this but its for readtext:

```
val inputStream = env.readTextFile(config.input.stream)
inputStream.print()

inputStream.map{str =>
  val strByte = str.getBytes()
  val thriftSerializer = new LazyBinaryThriftStructSerializer[CollectorPayload] {
    override def codec: CollectorPayload.type = CollectorPayload
  }
  val collectorPayload = thriftSerializer.fromBytes(strByte)
  collectorPayload
}.print()
```

Here it does not convert the data in proper format so wanted to read as binary file is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `readTextFile(path)` you can use `readFile(fileInputFormat, path)` and provide a `fileInputFormat` that meets your needs.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/io/class-use/FileInputFormat.html

Comment: file does not have any extension so how to define the format any example